# How to persist Google Map API Android v2 view state without making new request when rotating screen or navigate around?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have navigation drawer with fragments.
When app starts then the Google map view with markers on it appear on the screen. This is on of the fragment.

**Problem 1** 
When clicking another fragment and returning to the map fragment then it will make a new request to show the map. This happens when using replace().commit();

When using show() and hide() on fragments *then it is exactly what I need*(until rotating the screen). And
it will get kind of complicated when having more than 2 fragments on navigation drawer with all the checking isAdded() what to show and hide and so on. 
Is there a way to retain the Google map view without making new request with replace().commit(); ?

**Problem 2**
Same situation, when rotating the screen, Google map fragment makes a new request. And same thing happens when moving between different Activities

Because the Google Maps requests are limited it makes no sense to waste them that way.

I only need one request at the start of the app and then show the same state when navigating around the app.

This is the MapFragment file

```
public class MapFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LatLng location= new LatLng(58.6536852, 25.481182);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 7));


     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(59.408109, 24.326428)).title("marker 1"));
     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(59.481070, 25.654483)).title("marker 2"));

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution to this problem is to call the ***setRetainInstance(true)*** after you create you map fragment.

This method does the following functions:

- Keep the markers after orientation changed.
- Avoid creating new instances of Map Fragment after screen rotation.
- Avoid making extra request after each time map is created.

Here is an overview of code snippet:

```
public class RetainMapFragment extends MapFragment {

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  setRetainInstance(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I can't use this method in subFragment. My map fragment is in:   Navigation drawer fragment -> one of the sliding tabs. I tried to set it to navigation drawer fragment but not working as expected...

Comment: This post has a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770394/cant-retain-supportmapfragment-inside-fragment
It leads to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263503/how-can-i-save-the-fragment-when-i-rotate-the-screen
where I found a working solution but it is not recommended by adding orientation to android:configChanges in your AndroidManifest.xml. Like this
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
Is there a way to get same result but in a recommended way?