# How to prevent getChildFragmentManager cast to SupportMapFragment to crash when on Landscape mode

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

After trying this for about 3 days and digging through a few threads with no luck I have to send sos to anybody who can kindly look into my code.
The app functions flawlessly until I flip to landscape mode.

I'm implementing the solutions as describe in the threads below, so I move the code around in many ways but I've got errors like: **Nullpointer exception. View with id xxxx not found. Child already has a parent.**

No matter what I do, it keeps crashing. See please the threads I've followed but without luck

[thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301458/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil), [thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770394/cant-retain-supportmapfragment-inside-fragment), [thread 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263503/how-can-i-save-the-fragment-when-i-rotate-the-screen), [thread 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850573/cant-retain-nested-fragments)

To my disappointment I downloaded this nice app ([Airbnb google map](https://github.com/SkyTreasure/Airbnb-Android-Google-Map-View)) to see how they solved this problem but after I flip the phone it crashes exactly like mine. I'll probably send a note to the developer.

I read in the threads opinions are different and concepts given are interesting but I can't fix this. Would appreciate some new lines of code.

The code

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int CURSOR_LOADER_ID = 0;

    private Cursor initQueryCursor;
    private GetSet coord;
    private AppPreferences sPref;
    private LatLng home;
    private SupportMapFragment sMap;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final String FRAGMENT_LISTS =
                "net.simonvt.schematic.samples.ui.SampleActivity.LISTS";


    public MapsActivity() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sPref = new AppPreferences(getActivity());

        SyncAdapter.syncImmediately(getActivity(),
                sPref.getCoordBody("lat"),
                sPref.getCoordBody("lon"));
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
      //  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);

       // mMapCursor = new MapCursor(getActivity(), null, 0);


//        ConnectivityManager cm =
//                (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
//        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


//        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yelp_google_map, container, false);
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();

            sMap = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            mMap = sMap.getMap();

            initQueryCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(QuoteProvider.Quotes.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{QuoteColumns.URL, QuoteColumns.DISPLAY_PHONE, QuoteColumns.RATING_IMG,
                            QuoteColumns.ID_BUSINESS_NAME, QuoteColumns.DISPLAY_ADDRESS, QuoteColumns.POSTAL_CODE,
                            QuoteColumns.LATITUDE, QuoteColumns.LOGITUDE}, null,
                    null, null);

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            if (initQueryCursor != null) {

                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(initQueryCursor);
                initQueryCursor.moveToFirst();


                for (int i = 0; i < initQueryCursor.getCount(); i++) {


                    home = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(initQueryCursor.getString(initQueryCursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"))),
                            Double.valueOf(initQueryCursor.getString(initQueryCursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"))));
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).
                            title(initQueryCursor.getString(initQueryCursor.getColumnIndex("id_bussines_name"))));

                    initQueryCursor.moveToNext();
                    builder.include(home);
                }
                if (home != null) {
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 215, 210, 0));
                }
                initQueryCursor.close();

                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });

            }

            return v;
        }

         return null;

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), QuoteProvider.Quotes.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ QuoteColumns._ID, QuoteColumns.DISPLAY_ADDRESS, QuoteColumns.DISPLAY_PHONE,
                        QuoteColumns.RATING, QuoteColumns.URL, QuoteColumns.POSTAL_CODE, QuoteColumns.ID_BUSINESS_NAME,
                        QuoteColumns.LATITUDE,
                        QuoteColumns.LOGITUDE},
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        if (loader != null) {
            //     mMapCursor.swapCursor(data);
            initQueryCursor = data;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="mem.edu.joshua.MapsActivity"
                android:background="#009688">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is only one of the errors I get. Depending on what I change I get a different error like what I mentioned above**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: mem.edu.joshua, PID: 21406
                                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0081 (mem.edu.joshua:id/map) for fragment MapsActivity{425ff5b8 #2 id=0x7f0c0081 MapsActivity}
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1098)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Probably you should take a look at these links. 1) http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/retain-markers-on-screen-rotation-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-parcelable-latlng-points/  (2) http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html  (3) http://www.androidtrainee.com/retain-markers-on-screen-rotation-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-parcelable-latlng-points/

Comment: @Stallion, thanks for the help. I see link (2) is interesting. I had hope in that one but I keep getting. **IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x..81 for fragment.** Link (1) is similar to link (3). They focus on retaining the markers, I don't have problem with that because I'm using SQLite. Also link (1) uses a FragmentActivity and I don't have that I have a Fragment. My Main is in a different file in which I added this.                                 'if (mTaskFragment == null) {..}' after implementing in Main 'MapsActivity.TaskCallbacks' suggested by link (3)

Answer (score 0):

Take android:configChanges

```
<activity android:name=".yourFragmentactivity"
        android:label="@string/appname"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
      />
```

or take Landscape layout in layout-land like take in layout

Comment: Added your code to the manifest and didn't work. Created a new map_layout.xml(landscape) and didn't work either. Cleaned the project to try again but nothing. I got this. IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0081 (mem.edu.joshua:id/map) for fragment MapsActivity. I appreciate that you replied to my problem.